# Inkscape randomly crashes with Uniconvertor errors after switching windows/virtual desktops

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, python, inkscape

Basically, Inkscape will sometimes start opening dozens of errors, mostly with the following message:

> You need to install the UniConvertor software.
>   For GNU/Linux: install the package python-uniconvertor.
>   For Windows: download it from
>   https://sk1project.net/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor&op=download
>   and install into your Inkscape's Python location

Unfortunately, the package `python-uniconvertor` is not available for 18.04, and [appears](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=uniconvertor&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) to have been dropped after 17.10.

The only way to continue working is to `killall inkscape` and reopen.  The problem doesn't seem to happen while Inkscape is the active focused window; it only happens when I switch virtual desktops or Inkscape is hidden behind other windows.

[image: Image of the errors messages]